# Function with generic comprehension return type depending on input argument?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension, set-comprehension

Assuming I have a function that converts a character in a collection of strings like -

```
from typing import Collection

def replace_in_collection(input_collection: Collection[str]) -> Collection[str]:
    return [x.replace('a', 'b') for x in input_collection]
```

How do I create this function in a generic way, So that it returns the same collection type like the input type (not just a list like in the function example above).

So what I **want** is something that has the following behavior:

```
my_set = {'ab','ac'}
my_set_result = replace_in_collection(my_set)
type(my_set_result ) # --> set

my_list = ['ab','ac']
my_list_result = replace_in_collection(my_list)
type(my_list_result) # --> list
```

Is there a way to create this with a comprehension without using individual type checking?

Comment: I assume `for x in relevant_channels` is a typo and was supposed to be `for x in input_collection` ?

Comment: quite interesting for a first post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all the types of collections accept iterable as `__init__` parameter, that should work:

```
def replace_in_collection(input_collection):
    collection_type = type(input_collection)
    return collection_type(x.replace('a', 'b') for x in input_collection)
```

It does work for `set`, `list` and `tuple`.

And as Chris Rands noted, you should probably check if your input is of supported type:

```
if not isinstance(input_collection, (set, list, tuple)): # add other types if needed
    raise TypeError(f"input_collection must be of type set, list or tuple, not {type(input_collection).__name__}")
```

Comment: Use `type(obj)` instead of `obj.__class__`. Directly accessing `__magic__` names outside a class is considered bad style, as those are mainly implementation support for either operators or operator-like functions.

Comment: it might be worth explicitly checking that the type falls into set, list or tuple (or dict). for other types this might give errors or unexpected results

Comment: @Chris_Rands indeed, but this was already quite explicitely mentionned.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych as far as I'm concerned I wouldn't add any such type-checking as long as the contract is clearly documented - it's Python, and the norm is duck-typing (we have Ada for strict type-checking xD). And if you _really_ want to add type checking, at least do it the Python way: use an ABC that defines a collection of strings that takes an iterable yielding string as `__init__` params, register known good types (list, tuple, set...) as subclasses of your ABC, and check against this ABC.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers where?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: in the very first sentence of the answer and in the note below the code snippet. For released or production-grade code it should of course need to be part of the docstring.

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Well, then you would need to use these custom classes for list, set, etc. (correct me if I misunderstood). AFAIC, using `isinstance` for a type checking is quite common, so I believe it is a viable solution for OPs needs. Though, I agree that leaving it out is also a good solution :). And type checking in Python is more library style.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych " then you would need to use these custom classes for list, set"> nope, why ? That's (part of) the point of ABCs, you can dynamically register existing types. And you still do the check with `isinstance(obj, YourABC)`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych also wrt/ typechecking the collection, if you go that way, you should also typecheck that it only contains strings (or, at least, objects understanding the `.replace(x, y)` message) ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers `obj.__class__` is used in `functools.singledispatch` to determine the object class, and it is better than `type` if we want to support proxy object, since `type` will always be the "true" class, while `__class__` can be overridden by property, such that a proxy can pretend to have the same class as the object it act for.